# Multi level drop down, side menu does not work in ng-cloak

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating web app based on this bootstrap template:
http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html

But i have problem with multilevel drop down list. In my project i'm using angular and this is my main index:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div ui-view="navbar" ng-cloak=""></div>
    </div>      
    <div class="well" ui-view="content" id="page-wrapper"></div>
    <...list of source file>
</body>
```

In ui-view navbar i have my navigation bar, the top and the left menu. When in added multilevel dropdown in this navbar, the dropdown does not work correctly, it is visible but its not hide on click. However when i added it bellow the div wrapper everything is working fine, and i have no idea why in main index it works and in my wrapper doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to ui-view, but it's too hard. because how to control other ui-views I dont know.
if you want check my directive module fsm-accordion.js in my repo : https://github.com/fsma/angularjs-sb-admin2

thx Marco.
here the code, I hope this helps you Pulkownik.

```
<!-- side menu--> 
    <li class="sidebar-search">
        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
        </div>
        <!-- /input-group -->
    </li>
    <!-- side menu -->
    <li ng-repeat="item in menu"  id="menu{{$id}}" >
        <a fsm-menu sub-data="{{item.scndmenu ? true : false}}" ng-href="{{item.url}}">    
            <i class="fa {{item.css}} fa-fw"></i> 
            {{item.title}}
            <span ng-if="item.scndmenu ? true : false" class="fa arrow"></span>
        </a>
        <ul id="scndmenu"  class="nav nav-second-level" >
            <li  ng-repeat="subitem in item.scndmenu" id="menusncd{{$id}}">
                <a fsm-menu sub-data="{{subitem.thrdmenu ? true : false}}" ng-href="{{subitem.url}}"> 
                    {{subitem.title}}
                    <span ng-if="subitem.thrdmenu ? true : false" class="fa arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <ul id="thrdmenu"  class="nav nav-third-level " >
                  <li ng-repeat="sub2item in subitem.thrdmenu" id="menuthrd{{$id}}">
                        <a ng-href="{{sub2item.url}}"> 
                            {{sub2item.title}}
                        </a>
                  </li>     
               </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>        
    </li>
    <!-- /side menu-->     

    angular.module('fsmAccordion', [])
       .directive('fsmMenu', ['$document', '$window',
           function($window, $document) {
               return {
                   restrict: 'EAC',
                   scope: "@",
                   link: function(scope, element, attr) {
                       element.on('click', function(e) {
                           var liElementId = e.target.closest('li').id;
                           for (var i = 0; i < $('#' + liElementId).parent().children().length; i++) {
                               if (attr.subData == "true") {
                                   e.preventDefault();
                               }
                               if ($($('#' + liElementId).parent().children()[i]).hasClass("active")) {
                                       $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
                               }
                           }
                           if ($('#' + liElementId + " ul").css("display") == "none") {
                               if (attr.subData == "true") {
                                   e.preventDefault();
                               }
                               $('#' + liElementId).addClass('active');

                           }
                       });
                   }
               };
           }
       ]);
```